# Array transformation

Tags: java, arrays, transformation

I am far away from fully understanding Arrays and am really struggling with this. Here is the problem: I need to manipulate an array of ints. My program takes two values separated by comma; first value is the size of the array and the second the type of transformation. Define a constant MAXSIZE that represents the size of the array and is initialized to contain values from 0 to MAXSIZE. Based on the input the program should print out each transformation: halve, double, absolute and accumulate. I think my code doesn't even get to the cases method. The last couple of lines of my code do not want to get formatted for some reason, I finish up with return arrayList;

```
public class Game {

     public static void main(String[] args) {

     Scanner input =  new Scanner(System.in);
     input.useDelimiter("[,\n]");
     System.out.println("Enter size of array and case, separated by comma: ");

     final int MAXSIZE = input.nextInt();
     String transformation = input.next();
     int arrayList[] = new int[MAXSIZE +1];
     for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.length; i++) {
            arrayList[i] = i;
        }

     for(int i = 1; i<arrayList.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(arrayList[i] + "\n");
     }
     System.out.print(transformation);

     cases(transformation, arrayList);

     }

     public static void caseDouble(String transformation, int[] arrayList) {
            for(int i = 1; i<arrayList.length; i++) {
                arrayList[i] = arrayList[i]*2;
            }   
            for(int i = 1; i<arrayList.length; i++) {
                System.out.print(arrayList[i] + "\n");
         }

     }
     public static void caseAccumulate(String transformation, int[] arrayList) {
            int total = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i<arrayList.length; i++) {
                total += arrayList[i]/arrayList.length;
                System.out.println(arrayList[total]);   
            }
        }
     public static void caseAbsolute(String transformation, int[] arrayList) {
         for(int i = 1; i<arrayList.length;i++) {
             System.out.print(Math.abs(arrayList[i]));
         }
     }
     public static void caseHalve(String transformation, int[] arrayList) {
         for(int i = 1; i<arrayList.length;i++) {
             System.out.print(arrayList[i]/2);
         }
     }

     public static int[] cases(String transformation, int[] arrayList) {
         switch(transformation) {
         case "absolute":
             caseAbsolute(transformation, arrayList);
                 break;
         case "halve":
             caseHalve(transformation, arrayList);
                 break;
         case "accumulate":
             caseAccumulate(transformation, arrayList);
                break;
         case "double":
             caseDouble(transformation, arrayList);
```

Comment: No question, no answer.

Comment: whats wrong with my code? why is it not working? suggestions on what should be changed?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Is it no printing anything at all?

Comment: I added the extra System.out.prints to see if it's taking the array and transformation correctly. So it is printing the array and transformation based on the input.

Comment: So, it's no printing the result then?

Comment: nope, its not getting to the cases method where its suppose to decide what the transformation is

Comment: Put the code in a debugger and see where it's going -- even some trace statements might be enough.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid putting spaces between the comma and the transformation name when you are giving the input.

E.g.
type
`10,absolute`
instead of
`10, absolute`.

Comment: oh WOW, thanks. So my caseDouble is correct and I fixed my caseHalve as well. Thank you thank you!